# Vue JS data object not available within my methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting a little bit confused by Vue JS and how it is working. I have the following component:

```
Vue.component('careers', {
  template: `
  <div class="context">
    <div v-for="career in careerData">
      <h1>{{ career.fields.jobTitle }}</h1>
      {{ career.fields.jobDescription }}
    </div>
  </div>`,

  data: function() {
    return {
     careerData: []
    }
  },

  created: function() {
   this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      client.getEntries()
      .then(entries => {
        this.careerData = entries.items;
      });
      for (var i = 0, len = this.careerData.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log('Success');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This line within my `then()` function assigns an Array to my data object `careerData`.

```
this.careerData = entries.items
```

When I try to run this `for`:

```
  for (var i = 0, len = this.careerData.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log('Success');
  }
```

It doesn't work because `this.careerData.length` appears to have no data in it, it's just an empty array however when I try running my component within my HTML the data is displayed perfectly on the page.

Any idea where I might be going wrong here, it's as if I can't use `this.careerData` in any of my methods. Any idea why I can't access this data even known I have assigned it in my `fetchData` method already? It's very strange the data manages to get to the front end perfectly however I can't seem to use it anywhere else within my methods.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: I'm wonder why you are iterating twice through careerData array ? Basically why you are doing that inside fetchData method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the for loop outside the `then` and since it's an async operator, the array is still empty when you run the for loop.

put it inside the `then` function:

```
fetchData: function() {
      client.getEntries()
      .then(entries => {
         this.careerData = entries.items;

         for (var i = 0, len = this.careerData.length; i < len; i++) {
            console.log('Success');
         }
      });

    }
```